# Cost living or CPI (consumer price index) by city in de US

Tags: data-request, data.gov, us-census, cpi

I'm looking for data on cost of living per city from official U.S. sources.

So far I've only been able to find this data for states or counties like the following to examples:

- [Living Wage Calculation for Alabama](http://livingwage.mit.edu/states/1) (MIT)
- [Census.gov 'Housing' publications](https://www.census.gov/library/publications/2010/compendia/databooks/housing.html) (*Cost of Living Indicators — Housing, Public University, Hospital Stays, Energy Expenditures, and Utilities* Excel sheet)

Answer (score 3):

No 'official' numbers, but user contributed data:

[Numbeo](https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/) has city and country data (Free registration required for some parts).

> Numbeo is the world’s largest database of user contributed data about cities and countries worldwide. Numbeo provides current and timely information on world living conditions including cost of living, housing indicators, health care, traffic, crime and pollution.

Expatistan has a [Cost of living index](https://www.expatistan.com/cost-of-living), per country or per city

> Collaborative international cost of living index. You enter the prices, we make the comparisons.